# Why my AJAX function blocks the header of PHP that I have on my page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am doing a program in `PHP` (MVC) in which I need to delete a row from the database when I click on a link on the View side. So, when I click on the link, the following `ajax` function it is called.

```
var deleteCar = function(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/project/car/deleteCar/" + id,
        success: function(response){

        }
   });
}
```

but I do not want to send any data so it is the reason why I put it as above.

Then, in the Controller side I have the following method:

```
public function deleteCar($id)
{
    //Here I call the function to delete the Car that I send by id. It works fine.

    header('Location: http://localhost/project/car');
}
```

If I call directly the method `deleteCar` on the link without `Ajax` the header works properly but in the same moment I use `Ajax` to call it, I have to refresh the page to see the content that I have modified, I mean, that the `Car` have been deleted.

**The code works fine, just I do not want to refresh the page after AJAX function had finished.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing the use case is to allow the app to work when the user does not have JS enabled - so they just click the links and get a non-AJAX experience. In this case you probably want to redirect ONLY if the page was requested via GET, not POST. something like

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    header('Location: http://localhost/project/car');
}
```

is likely what you are looking for.

You will then have to actually remove the element representing the car from the DOM in your success handler, with something like:

```
var deleteCar = function(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/project/car/deleteCar/" + id,
        success: function(response){
            $('#car-row-' + id).remove();
        }
   });
}
```

(that won't be it exactly, it depends how the HTML of your page is setup how exactly you will do this).

I believe the key thing to understand here is - when your PHP function has completed it has removed the car from the database, but the browser still has the same HTML it got from the page originally. Just sending an AJAX request won't change that. If you want the HTML in the browser to change to reflect the new state of the database, you will NEED to do one of two things:

1. Refresh the page, so the entire thing is rebuilt by PHP based on the current database state
2. Use javascript to change the HTML in the browser, to reflect the changes you have made to the database state.

Comment: I did not think about if the user does or does not have the JS enabled or not. It is just a personal project that it is only for me so I do not exactly understand what you mean that my app click the link and get a non-AJAX experience. By parts (as the directives of my project says): I have to press some link to do a delete function with AJAX. So, the behaviour of my app it is: Click the link -> AJAX function -> Controller -> Model (delete from database) -> Again Controller (make my header refresh the page). I expect it will be more clear now.

Comment: Yes, it is like the first one method that you add now. When I refresh the page, the data it is rebuilt by PHP on the HTML page. It is why I need to use a header.

Comment: OK. In that case I believe the confusion lies in your use of headers with AJAX - there is no header you can pass in the response of an AJAX response that will cause the page making the request redirect/refresh. If you want to show the new state after the request you have to either reload the whole page from server (you could force this in your success handler with something like `window.location.reload();`), or do the work manually to change the HTML with JS

Comment: But in that case, I mean, if I use `window.location.reload();` how can I tell to AJAX from PHP that the changes on the database have been done?

Comment: It is rare that you will ever find yourself with the need to pass particular headers to an AJAX request - if you find yourself in such a situation there is a good chance that you may e on the wrong path. (You may need to sometimes be explicit in the mime-type that you are returning, or control the response code, but those are the only relevant headers for AJAX requests I can think of)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are using to access the DB, but it should give you a way to tell how many rows were affected by your query. Maybe if you check that is >0 (or whatever conditions suit your usage to tell that the delete was successful) and based on that, echo either 1 or 0 at the end of your deleteCar function in PHP. in your success handler in JS, check the value of response to see if you got 1 (success) or 0 (failure). If you got 1, you can run window.location.reload(), otherwise display an error message to the user?

Comment: I was thinking about if it is possible to do something like `return true` on my `deleteCar` in PHP method in the place that I am using right now the header. To go to the AJAX function. Or maybe an echo or whatever.

Comment: if you are more worried about the timeline, that is, whether your db changes will be done by the time the browser receives the AJAX response, again it depends on how you are accessing the DB, but you can generally assume functions in PHP are blocking - that is, by the time your code progresses to the next statement after the one where you delete from the DB, it should be done

Comment: then you are thinking exactly right :). Echo is the way to go - what you return from the PHP function won't be available in the JS function (unless you are using a framework that specifically makes it available). Here's an example for passing data between PHP and JS with AJAX: http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/ - the key function in PHP to look into is `json_encode`.

Comment: Ok, the `json_encode` was the clue. Now I have it. Thanks for the help provided! I think you should edit the answer with the new answer (that I upvote in your comments). Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong on so many levels but it's difficult to put in words. It's subtle.
Long story short - think about jquery.ajax as of another *virtual* tab of you browser.
When you make ajax-request to the server - you create *new* *virtual* tab. 
You php header could affect this *virtual tab* and redirect it where that header defined.
But it will redirect that *virtual tab*, not your current tab - if that makes sense.

What are your options? On success - make redirect with pure javascript.

```
success: function(response){
    location.href = "http://localhost/project/car";
}
```

This would be the basic way to solve your problem.

Comment: But how can I know that the PHP have finished after I have called its function from AJAX?

Comment: ajax reads response from server. server is forming response while executing your php script. when job is done server-side, server's response is finished. By the way - server can output some kind of message for ajax when result of Delete was OK, and another message when Delete failed. Your ajax must be ready for these cases: 1. ajax.fail - event when there was error connecting to server or server is forming request too long. 2. ajax.load - ajax could fetch response from server and that response - was DeleteOK message - yey 3. ajax.load - ajax could fetch message but it was DeleteFail message.

Comment: 'By the way - server can output some kind of message for ajax when result of Delete was OK' - but this is a system you must design yourself for your needs how it feel right for you. It's not hard.